# String to Datetime with pandas : TypeError: <class 'list'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas Dataframe with the column Date with following structure:

```
352    [2012-01-12 05:04:58]
353    [2008-07-16 20:38:21]
354    [2009-05-12 01:05:48]
355    [2012-01-12 05:04:58]
356    [2018-01-05 15:06:41]
357    [2017-07-17 22:03:43]

Name: Date, Length: 358, dtype: object
```

As you see these are 'objects" with . I want to convert them to Datetime objects. So I used the pandas function:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-185-adf5e63a666b>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 451, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/py35thesis/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/tools/datetimes.py", line 368, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 492, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 744, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas/_libs/tslib.pyx", line 677, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
TypeError: <class 'list'> is not convertible to datetime
```

Comment: `df.date.apply(pd.to_datetime)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say your column name is date, you can use apply

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x[0]))

    date
352 2012-01-12 05:04:58
353 2008-07-16 20:38:21
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt see that. :)